# Bash script appending ^M to filename

Tags: bash

In one of my bash scripts, I am creating a file by repeatedly using `echo` with output redirection to append to the file. The resulting file, however, is not named properly, but always has an unprintable `^M` character appended to the end. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? The following simple script demonstrates the problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Should create 'concat.txt' instead creates 'concat.txt^M'
outfile="concat.txt"
echo "'"$outfile"'"
for item in "Able" "Baker" "Charlie"; do
    echo $item >> $outfile
done
```

System: Ubuntu 9.04 (x64)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would suspect that you edited the file somewhere that added DOS-style line endings. Run your  file through `dos2unix` to get rid of them.

```
dos2unix yourscriptfile
```

Comment: To check for Windows line-endings, run `cat -vt file.ext` and look for `^M`'s.

Answer (score 5):

`^M` is what you would see at the end of every line if you set the line ending to unix mode when the file was written initially in dos mode where the line endings are `\r\n`

So, while you see

```
echo $item >> $outfile
```

unix sees:

```
echo $item >> $outfile^M
```

First,

```
:set ff=unix
```

Then:

```
:%s/\r//
```

to remove the ^M

**EDIT**

For some silly reason I assumed you're using vim. Maybe because it's the only editor that I've seen show the `\r` as `^M`. Anyway, do what Dennis Williamson said, use the `dos2unix` tool.

Comment: That's    `vi`?

Comment: oh sorry, for some silly reason I assumed he's using vi